# I don't use <algorithm> header, but sort() is available

Tags: c++, header, std

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int arrr[5] = {21,124,1521,123,1};
    sort(arrr,arrr+5);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see above, I don't use `#include <algorithm>` but I can use the `sort()` function! Why? I don't know.

`<iostream>` doesn't have `#include <algorithm>`

Please tell me why this works.

I'm using Xcode on Mac OSX.

Comment: You're implementation includes `<algorithm>` (somehow), when you include `<iostream>`. That isn't guaranteed, so don't bet the farm on it. Follow the standard and include the headers mandated by the APIs you're using.

Comment: Obviously, `<iostream>` includes another header than in turn includes `<algorithm>`, that is the only way this could work. Like WhozCraig said, don't rely on this behavior. When you want to include a given function, `#include` the function's header yourself.

Answer (score 4):

In C++, including any standard header is allowed (but certainly not required) to have the same effect as including any or all other standard headers.

In this case, it appears that some part of the implementation of `<iostreams>` used an algorithm from `<algorithm>`, so your inclusion of `<iostreams>` accidentally included `<algorithm>` as well.

Of course, you don't want to depend on this--on a different implementation, your code can (and often will) fail. Even updating your compiler (or possibly even just using different compiler flags) could prevent your code from compiling.

Comment: oh thank you. I understood

Comment: I'd called it "incidentally" rather than "accidentally".  I'm guessing it was intentional.

Comment: @Eljay: It may have been intentional on the part of the people who wrote the header, but clearly wasn't on his part.

Comment: @JerryCoffin • fair enough.  An incidentally by the maker, an accidentally by the user.

Answer (score 1):

Whether standard headers include other headers is unspecified. It is not guaranteed that a standard header won't include any other standard headers. [Standard (draft)](http://eel.is/c++draft/res.on.headers) quote:

> [library] / [requirements] / [conforming]
>   / [res.on.headers]
>
> 1. A C++ header may include other C++ headers. [snip]

So, `std::sort` happened to be declared, since it happened to have been included by `<iostream>`. But that was neither guaranteed by the standard, nor is it against the standard.